# How to launch Civilization IV with a desired mod automatically loaded?

Tags: mods, civilization-4

I am playing Rise of Mankind mod for Civilization IV Beyond The Sword, Steam version. But every time I launch the game it starts without any mod loaded.

Is it possible to setup the launcher so that automatically load the desired mod at the first shot?

Answer (score 7):

So bwarner's answer is *almost* right.

What it should look like is:

```
Target: "C:\program files\steam\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization iv beyond the sword\Beyond the Sword\Civ4BeyondSword.exe" mod=\Fall from Heaven 2
Start in: "c:\program files\steam\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization iv beyond the sword\Beyond the Sword\Mods"
```

The way it finds the mod from the directory is by using the `Start in:`.  This allows you to place your mod in a directory that you feel is more comfortable.  For example, if you want to edit your version of `Fall from Heaven 2` because you think the Armageddon counter is good, but should really be about 15% faster; you can make a copy in a different directory and modify appropriately without affecting other users of your computer.  Bear in mind, if you load the mod from Civ 4 it'll use the default path.

Comment: For what it's worth, in order to get Civ to recognize the mod I needed to put quotes around the `"mod=\Fall from Heaven 2"` portion as well.

Comment: @Bobson Thanks, man. I just bought a(nother) copy of civ 4 with the humble bundle and was having a bit of frustration with the not working shortcut. Works fine after moving that quotation mark.

Answer (score 4):

I know you can do it with a link to the direct EXE by modifying the target of your desktop shortcut to add a mod= at the end like this

"...\Civ4BeyondSword.exe" mod=mods\BOB

Where BOB should be replaced with the name of the mod you want to launch.  Not sure if the fact that you have the Steam version will make that any different.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me (note all the quotes):

```
Target: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -applaunch 8800 "mod=\Fall from Heaven 2"
Start in: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization IV Beyond the Sword\Beyond the Sword\Mods"
```

Answer (score 1):

Steves answer is good (and might have been the only way to do it in 2012), however you can also use the Steam launch options. So:

Rightclick the game > Properties > Set launch options, and there you can configure "mod=\Fall from Heaven 2".

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was specifically about Steam, this is what worked for me using Steam Proton (on Linux):

1. Right-click the game > Properties
2. Under *Launch Options* in the *General* section, set the `mod` parameter to the exact name of the directory the mod is installed in. Double backslashes are necessary to escape the backslash, e.g. for Planetfall:

   ```
   %command% "mod=\\Planetfall v16"
   ```